# How to redirect to another web application in the same server?

Tags: asp.net

I have two web applications in the same server like this:

```
/basedir/app1path/default1.aspx

/basedir/app2path/default2.aspx
```

How can I redirect form `default1.aspx` to `default2.aspx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code-behind:

```
Response.Redirect("/basedir/app2path/default2.aspx", false);
```

(The `false` prevents a `ThreadAbortException` getting thrown by the redirect)

Or using a 301 server redirect?